# How to get line number from a text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program where i have 2 text files and i want 2 get one line from each text file like this

```
    Dim pathlocal as string= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\Test\"
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(pathlocal & "to.txt")
    Dim allLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
        allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    Loop
    reader.Close()
   For Each file In allLines
        If pathlocal & "from.txt".Contains(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file).Name) Then
            'Get line number of from.txt where you found file.name
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

I appreciate the help(and pls try 2 make it simple sorry but i am not that good THANX)

Comment: Have you figured your problem out?

Comment: Yes i did thanx to minimalist and sorry 4 the late reply just now i saw his answer and ur comment

Comment: Ok, you should accept his answer.

Comment: I did thank him but i am actually new to the site i thought if i found an answer useful i will vote his but it said my reputation is low or something and by accept do u mean there is an option make this the correct answer or something sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Public Class Form1
Dim path As String = "Your Path"
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim indxto As Integer = 0
    Dim indxfrom As Integer = 0
    Dim allLinesto As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(path & "\" & "to.txt").ToList
    Dim allLinesfrom As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(path & "\" & "from.txt").ToList
    For Each line As String In allLinesto
        indxto = allLinesto.IndexOf(line)
        'Debug.Print(line & " " & indxto.ToString)
        For Each item As String In allLinesfrom
            indxfrom = allLinesto.IndexOf(item)
            If line = item Then
                Debug.Print(item & " " & indxfrom.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a couple of Integer typed variables to help with this.  One stores the line number as you iterate through the list and the other stores the line number you are seeking.  Plus, by changing your For Each approach to a Do Until or Do While approach you could potentially speed things up if the target is found prior to the last line of the file.

```
Dim intLineNumber As Integer = -1
Dim intLineCursor As Integer

Do Until (intLineCursor = allLines.Count OrElse intLineNumber <> -1)

    If pathlocal & "from.txt".Contains(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(allLines(intLineCursor)).Name) Then

        intLineNumber = intLineCursor '+ 1 if you are displaying to a user since the lower bound is 0 based.

    End If      

    'Increment the cursor variable.
    intLineCursor += 1

Loop
```

Comment: Thanx 4 trying 2 help me but it says conversion from string to type boolean is not valid at the if statement do you know why this happened? THANX

Comment: I have your first seven lines of code plus the code block I posted in the answer in VS 2010 and I can compile fine.  Are you getting this error at run time?  If so, what line?

Comment: maybe it is because i made a new program just to test your code but still i added all what i need in it and i still get the error in the if statemenet the first line of it.Here are the details i provided screenshots to the code,error and the text files http://www.mediafire.com/download/7dcfzweaw3c6jv9/The_code.docx